# Restrict number of characters in DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, that is created dyanically. It contains 2 columns. The first being the header and the second column is the one that allows user input. The 2nd column is a mixture of DataGridViewCells and DataGridViewComboBoxCell. 
Each row has a limit on the number of characters that are allowed within the DataGridViewCell.

What i would like to do is on KeyPress for that cell limit the number of characters that can be entered and popup a message if the length is greater than the limit. Does anyone have any example code for this.

I am using c#, Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 2):

If you have a column type of `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, you can simply set the property `MaxInputLength` that would limit the length of the input text.

```
var column2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column2.MaxInputLength = 5;
dataGridView.Columns.Add(column2);
```

To manually add code for the `KeyPress` event handler try the following:

```
TextBox columnTextBox; // Form field

private void DataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (columnTextBox != null)
        columnTextBox.KeyPress -= TextBox_KeyPress;
}

private void DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    columnTextBox = e.Control as TextBox;

    if (columnTextBox != null)
        columnTextBox.KeyPress += TextBox_KeyPress;
}

private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    // here your logic with textBox
}
```

Set event handlers for `DataGridView`:

```
dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView_EditingControlShowing;
dataGridView.CellEndEdit += DataGridView_CellEndEdit;
```

Comment: @alexsander-petrov, I dont have a specific DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column. I have a DataGridView, which i then add 2 columns to it. The first is a header. The second is where the user inputs the data, but the type of cell is dependent on the field type of the header which is created dynamically. If the fieldtype of a field is date, a calendar cell is created or if it is a string, which only allows specific values, then a combocell cell is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own DatagridViewColumn Class i think. Take a look at this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180996.aspx

Comment: Is it possible for you to consider including a worked example of the **KeyPress** event handler in your answer?